# Is an idle temperature of 66°C for the A10-6800K CPU normal?

Tags: cpu, temperature

I have an A10-6800K CPU and Piriform Speccy says that my CPU temp is 66 celcius in idle, the same goes for HWMonitor.

Is this normal/ideal? I have a [Coolermaster V10](http://www.coolermaster.com/product/Detail/cooling/cpu-air-cooler/v10.html) with a [HAF 932 case](http://www.coolermaster-usa.com/product.php?product_id=2810).

Answer (score 4):

The A10-6800K is a quad-core 4.1 GHz CPU which sports a [100 watt TDP](http://www.vortez.net/articles_pages/amd_richland_a10_6800k_review,2.html) and [draws about 35 W at idle](http://www.vortez.net/articles_pages/amd_richland_a10_6800k_review,5.html), basically a spiffed-up Trinity chip.

Here is a page that gives [some CPU operating temperatures](http://www.buildcomputers.net/cpu-temperature.html). Under the AMD Trinity heading, you'll find the following figures specifically for the A10-6800K:

> Idle temperature: 28 to 35°C
>   Normal temperature: 50 to 55°C
>   Max temperature: 74°C

The implication is that **your 66°C at idle is quite a long way above normal.** In fact, it is about three times as far above ambient as you should be able to expect (assuming ambient 20°C, you're seeing 46°C above ambient rather than up to 15°C above ambient), a fair bit above normal operating temperature, and close enough to the maximum rated temperature that at least I would have some concerns about the longevity of the chip under those circumstances.

At these temperatures, even ambient temperature in the case plays a relatively minor role, although if you do have an appropriate thermometer handy it can't hurt to just measure the temperature inside the case at the same time. I would **suspect insufficient heat transfer from the CPU die,** or possibly a malfunctioning active cooling system (but then you'd probably know).

Hence, my suggestion is the same as [to a recent, similar question](https://superuser.com/a/677128/53590): **apply new thermal paste first** and see if that helps. Remember that ordinary, still air is a great thermal insulator, and in the case of a CPU, what you definitely *do not* want is a thermal insulator *anywhere* between the hot CPU die on the one side and the heatsink and fans on the other.

Comment: I'll follow your advice, and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: @Secret Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Speccy does not report the correct temperatures for this family of CPUs/APUs.

For instance, my A8-5600K is reported at 80 C by speccy at more or less idle speeds, but Asus AI Suite 3 says it's 46 C.

I think this should explain it:

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-2122665/understanding-temperature-amd-cpus-apus.html

They recommend you use AMD Overdrive to check your temperatures, though I have never used it.

https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/amd-overdrive